# Why use C typedefs rather than #defines?

Tags: c, standards

What advantage (if any) is there to using `typedef` in place of `#define` in C code?

As an example, is there any advantage to using

```
typedef unsigned char UBYTE
```

over

```
#define UBYTE unsigned char
```

when both can be used as

```
void func()
{
        UBYTE byte_value = 0;

        /* Do some stuff */

        return byte_value;
}
```

Obviously the pre-processor will try to expand a `#define` wherever it sees one, which wouldn't happen with a `typedef`, but that doesn't seem to me to be any particular advantage or disadvantage; I can't think of a situation where either use wouldn't result in a build error if there was a problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you do a typedef of an array type, you'll see the difference:

```
typedef unsigned char UCARY[3];
struct example { UCARY x, y, z; };
```

Doing that with a #define... no, let's not go there.

[EDIT]: Another advantage is that a debuggers usually know about typedefs but not #defines.

Comment: Quoth the preprocessor: "Abuse me, Abuse me .. Make me feel wanted!!" +1

Comment: I do do preprocessor abuse a fair bit, but not for types unless there's no other way. (I needed it *once* in the past 20 years when writing code to do cross-platform 64-bit integer handling. That was surprisingly tricky on the compilers available at the time, and ended up with more #ifdefs than I'd have preferred.)

Comment: @missingno: Function *types* are very difficult to use without typedef, but once you've got one, you can use it to declare a function as well as pointers to such a function (which are only slightly harder to use, and not at all once defanged with a typedef…)

Answer (score 3):

Well, coming from a C++, perspective, a C++ programmer using your code might have something like:

```
template<typename T> class String
{
     typedef T char_type;
     // ...
};
```

Now, if in your C code, you've written something like:

```
#define char_type uint32_t // because I'm using UTF-32
```

Well, you are going to be causing serious trouble for the users of your header file. With typedefs, you can change the value of the typedef within different scopes... while scopes aren't respected with #defines.

I know that you've labeled this C, but C programmers and C++ programmers need to realize that their headers might be used by each other... and this is one of those things to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

1) Probably the great advantage is a cleaner code.
Usually abusing macros transforms the code in an unmaintainable mess, known as: 'macro soup'.

2) By using a typedef you define a new type. Using a macro you actually substitute text. The compiler is surely more helpful when dealing with typedef errors.

Answer (score 2):

With `#define` all you get is string substitution during preprocessing. `typedef` introduces a new type. This makes it easier to find possible problems in your code and in case of any the compiler might be able to give you more detailed information.

Comment: not quite a *new* type - it's an alias for an existing type - but a type it is, yes

Answer (score 2):

- Debuggers and compiler error messages become more helpful if the compiler/debugger knows about the type. (this is also why you should use constants and not defines where possible)
- Arrays, as others have shown
- you can restrict typedefs to a smaller scope (say, a function). Even more true in C++.